# html that work on PC but not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am completely new to jquery and jquery mobile. If the following questions that embarrasses you, i feel sorry for that.

Recently, i try to learn how to write a page to get data from google sheet by using json and jquery. After a bit of hard work, i successfully get the expected result.

After this, i want to have one step further, and try to make it work on mobile.
I know jquery mobile is the interface that make it work on mobile, but i totally lost in learning jquery mobile. Therefore, i would like to seek help from you guys. Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">




  <style>
  table,
    th,
    td {
      margin: 10px 0;
      border: solid 1px #333;
      padding: 2px 4px;
      font: 15px Verdana;
    }
    
    th {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    //#loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 16px solid blue;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  @keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  </style>
  <!--script src="cordova.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>


  <form>
    Select Predrill Hole Number:
    <select id="HoleList" onchange="Predrill()">
            <option>Pose 1</option>
            <option>Pose 2</option>
        </select>

    <name="name" id="name">


  </form>
  <br>

  <input type="button" onclick="update_value()" value="Update" />
  <input type="button" onclick="read_value()" value="Read" />

  <div id="showData"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="" id="photo1"><img id="pic" src="" alt="">
    <a>


      <script>
        var script_url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzHtuKZACiuwQmCc8PqrRAK-nWm61ZtaZpy1Rr7c1Bub1GeThA/exec";

        // Make an AJAX call to Google Script

        function update_value() {
          $("#re").css("visibility", "hidden");
          document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "visible";

          var id1 = $("#id").val();
          var name = $("#name").val();

          var url = script_url + "?callback=ctrlq&name=" + name + "&id=" + id1 + "&action=update";

          var request = jQuery.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp"
          });
        }

        // print the returned data
        function ctrlq(e) {
          $("#re").html(e.result);
          $("#re").css("visibility", "visible");
          read_value();
        }

        function read_value() {
          $("#re").css("visibility", "hidden");
          document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "visible";
          var url = script_url + "?action=read";

          $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            // Set the variables from the results array

            // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
            var table = document.createElement("table");

            var header = table.createTHead();
            var row = header.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = "<b>ID</b>";
            cell2.innerHTML = "<b>Name</b>";

            // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
            for (var i = 0; i < json.records.length; i++) {

              tr = table.insertRow(-1);
              var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
              tabCell.innerHTML = json.records[i].Heading;
              tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
              tabCell.innerHTML = json.records[i].Information;
            }
            var myObj = json.records[0];
            document.getElementById("photo1").href = myObj.Photo1;
            document.getElementById("pic").src = myObj.Photo1;


            // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
            var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
            divContainer.innerHTML = "";
            divContainer.appendChild(table);
            document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "hidden";
            $("#re").css("visibility", "visible");
          });
        }


        function Predrill() {
          var HoleList = document.getElementById("HoleList");
          document.getElementById("name").value = HoleList.options[HoleList.selectedIndex].text;
        }
      </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loader"></div>

  <p id="re"></p>
</body>

<div align="center">
  <p> | All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question? also little side note: you can use `$('#id')` instead of `document.getElementById('id')` when using jquery

Comment: My question is how to make it work on mobile. Thank you!

Comment: First you should move the the `<form />` and other visible elements into the body because it could fail if you put them into the head.

Comment: i recommend reading [the documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/) and do what @floriangosse said.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not really familiar with jQuery mobile, but I can tell you the basics about an HTML document, maybe you could start from there:

Your html document should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

//Here will your html code be

</body>
</html>
```

Put all your links to stylesheets and script- tags containing the jquery CDN- links in the head-tag.

My advice is to keep css files and javascript files separate and not everything in 1 document, as it gets really unstructured and overwhelming that way. Keep your code clean from the start, that way you don't have to clean it all up later and it will get easier alot.

Hope it helps!
Ramon

PS: There are no bad questions, everybody started somewhere and I asked myself the same thing when I started, so just keep googling haha! Good luck!